# Npm child process live feed

Tags: node.js, npm, stdout, stderr, child-process

I am writing a CLI tool for a node.js app. Some of the commands have to run npm and show the results. This is what I have so far:

```
import {spawn} from 'child_process';

let projectRoot = '...';
let npm = (process.platform === "win32" ? "npm.cmd" : "npm"),
childProcess = spawn(npm, ["install"], { cwd: projectRoot });
childProcess.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
childProcess.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
childProcess.on('close', (code) => {
    // Continue the remaining operations
});
```

The command does run fine and outputs the results (or errors). However, it doesn't give me a live feed with the progress bar, etc. It waits until the entire operation is over and then dumps the output into the console.
I've tried different variations of the spawn configuration but I can't get it to show me the live feed.

I am on Windows 10 and use node.js 4 and npm 3.

Comment: did you tried running it with { stdio: 'inherit' } ?

Comment: For some reason, I thought I had tried that; obviously not since it actually worked this time. Thanks for that, but I am not sure if I understand the difference between using inherit vs piping the streams manually. Why would one work over the other? Anyway, if you want to submit an answer, go ahead and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments: Run the `spawn` with `{ stdio: 'inherit' }`.

However, good question is why the 'manual piping' does not do the same. I think that's because `npm` uses the 'fancy progress bar'. It probably uses some special way how to deal with stdout that does not play well with `process.stdout`. If you try some other long-running command (such as 'find ./'), your way of piping works fine.